# is it possible to obfuscate part of classes/packages in apk?

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I have developed one android application which is having set of activities,background service and some other utility packages(which are written on pure java), i don't want to obfuscate activities and background service but need to obfuscate utility packages(pure java code), is it possible to do so?if yes then how to enable it in my proguard.cfg file?

OR in more precise way:
Application is using some external jars which are added to project's lib folder, I want only these jars should get obfuscated and rest of application code(activities , service etc...) should not get obfuscated. How to achieve the same using eclipse and proguard.cfg?

Regards,
Piks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If proguard is activated then Android will automatically include the used library files when creating a signed APK in Eclipse, so you don't have to specify this.

If the package name of your application is different from the package names of your libraries then you can simply use a wildcard and add this to your proguard.cfg file

```
-keepnames class com.mypackagename.** {
 *;
}
```

If the packagename is the same, then you'll have to specify which classes should be obfuscated by hand, e.g.

```
-keepnames class com.mypackagename.MyApp {
 *;
}
-keepnames class com.mypackagename.subpackage.MyClass {
 *;
}
```